# Run bash without user config while still able to set bindings

Tags: bash

I would like to be able to run a script with the following two properties

1. Everything inside the script is run as if the bashrc was never sourced.
2. I can still set bindings that will remain after the script has completed.

For example
if my .bashrc looks like

```bsh
alias rm="echo don't use me"
```

I want to be able to run the following script such that

- `rm.me` is removed
- afterwards, running `fn` will echo `i am bound`

```bsh
rm rm.me
fn() { echo i am bound; }
```

If I run `bash my-script.sh` then `fn` isn't bound
And If I run `. my-script.sh` then my `rm` alias is used.

Comment: Is this specifically for defining functions?

Comment: @terdon Ideally I could define anything that would work by normally sourcing a file, but I'd be decently happy If I could get it with just functions.

Comment: Since you don't mention the option of sourcing that script at the beginning of your `.bashrc`, I'd assume you want to run it from an already open, interactive Bash instance. Is this correct?

Comment: Also: are you really looking for "as if the bashrc was never sourced", or would it be enough, for instance, to remove aliases from the current environment before running `my-script.sh` and redefining them afterwards?

Comment: @fra-san 1: yes that is correct. 2: I would like the first option, but the second option would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always disable alias expansion whilst you source the script:

```
shopt -u expand_aliases; . ./myscript.bash; shopt -s expand_aliases
```

(`myscript.bash` will still inherit the variables, functions, umasks, limits, traps, redirections, options, etc that you may have set in your `~/.bashrc`)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to automagically apply the changes made in a foreign shell execution environment to the current shell execution environment.

Here is a proof of concept of how you can partly do that without changing your `my-script.sh` script:

```bsh
{ . <(bash <(cat my-script.sh - <<'EOT'
declare -pf >&3
alias -p >&3
EOT
) 3>&1 1>&4); } 4>&1
```

This way, the content of `my-script.sh` is executed in its own non-ineractive `bash` instance, which neither sources `~/.bashrc` nor inherits aliases and non-exported variables and functions. `declare` and `alias` are concatenated to it to print out alias and function definitions from that environment. The file descriptor shuffling ensures the output of `my-script.sh` is printed on the outer standard output (by default, the terminal), while the `source` command is only fed with the output of the added `alias` and `declare`.
Note that (as [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640934/run-bash-without-user-config-while-still-able-to-set-bindings/641028?noredirect=1#comment1202579_641028)) the sourced content will undergo alias expansion, possibly defeating the whole point of this exercise.
Also, both the command line (e.g. in the output of `ps`) and the command name in the child Bash process (used, for instance, when printing error messages) will be less meaningful — the path of the temporary file created by the process substitution.

Alternatively, you may temporarily save part of the current environment, remove it, source your script and then restore the removed part. For aliases:

```bsh
aliases=$(alias -p)
unalias -a
. my-script.sh
eval "$aliases"
```

For functions:

```bsh
shopt -s extglob                             # (There likely
functions=$(declare -pf)                     # is a cleaner
readarray -t funcnames < <(declare -pF)      # way to
unset -f "${funcnames[@]#declare -f*(x) }"   # do this)
. my-script.sh
eval "$functions"
```

Again, it has to be noted that the content of `functions` will undergo alias expansion when `eval`uated.

Comment: *the content of my-script.sh is executed in its own non-ineractive bash instance*, but then you're sourcing the output of `declare -pf` upon which the bashrc aliases will be expanded.

Comment: Note that for functions that are exported, `declare -pF` outputs `declare -fx f`

Comment: The `eval "$functions"` will also undergo alias expansion.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for the remarks. Since you posted an answer about `expand_aliases` I preferred not to "fix" mine and add some warnings instead.